# What's the purpose of `(keyof FormValues & string) | string`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Hello ~ I am a newbie to TypeScript. I could not understand the purpose of `(keyof FormValues & string) | string`. Please help me.

```
export type FieldValues = Record<string, any>;

export type FieldName<FormValues extends FieldValues> =
  | (keyof FormValues & string)
  | string;

export type FieldValue<FormValues extends FieldValues> = FormValues[FieldName<
  FormValues
>];
```

Answer (score 1):

The type is wrong. `FieldName` type will always evaluate to `string` no matter what will be given as a type argument. Consider few examples:

```
type A = FieldName<{ a: string }> // A is string
type B = FieldName<{a: number, b: string}> // B is string
type C = FieldName<{c: boolean, d: string}> // C is string
```

The issue with this type is the union part :

```
export type FieldValues = Record<string, any>; // any object type with string keys

export type FieldName<FormValues extends FieldValues> =
  | (keyof FormValues & string) // doing interesection with string
  | string; // and everything goes to string because of this line
```

If we want to get any specific type, the last line `| string` ruins everything. As its just eats the first line. `keyof FormValues` is a subset of `string`, if we do the union we will get just a `string`. Really the whole type should be written like that:

```
export type FieldName<FormValues extends {}> = keyof FormValues & string

type A = FieldName<{ a: string }> // A is "a"
type B = FieldName<{ a: number, b: string }> // B is "a" | "b"
type C = FieldName<{c: boolean, d: string}> // C is "c" | "d"
type D = FieldName<{1: string}> // D is never - correct
```

Consider that I dont use anymore `FormFields` as `& string` ensures that our key is a string only. All types from A to D correctly narrows the result types, and for type with number key we got `never` as we consider only `string` keys.

Answer (score 1):

as @maciej-sikora pointed out the union of string ruined everything,
the keyof string-keyed type union string evaluates to string, 
but in rare scenarios, the code above *DOES* make some scene,

given you have a type that support any string as its key, but you may have a pre-defined set of keys, for example, an investigation form which have age and name, and any other fields the user may input as key,

using types defined below, vscode will give you a nice autocompletion in odd ways, for example:
[image: autocompletion works]

but if you define the type with just string:

[image]

notice that even the first image was auto-completed with just keys from `Form`, actually it can be filled with any string value, perhaps the code you supplied has something to do with this feature/bug.